# Trouble with click function on custom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Im trying to create a plugin (not a good work but just want to learn) and im having trouble with adding a clic event.

Here is the plugin:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.selectMe = function() {

        return this.filter(".selectMe").each(function() {

            var sel = $(this);
            var listOpt = "";

            /* Hide the <select> tag and create a new element ".selectMe" */
            sel.css("display","none");
            var selName = sel.attr("name");
            sel.after("<div id='"+selName+"' class='selectMe'><div class='selLabel'><span></span><i class='fa fa-lg fa-angle-down pull-right'></i></div><div class='selOptions'></div></div>");

            /* Look for <option> of his parent and add them to the new element*/
            sel.find("option").each(function() {
                var optVal = $(this).val();
                var optText = $(this).text();
                /*listOpt += "{"+optVal+"} ";*/
                listOpt += "<li data-value='"+optVal+"'>"+optText+"</li>";
            });
            $("#"+selName+" .selOptions").html("<ul>"+listOpt+"</ul>");

        });

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<select class="selectMe" name="cars">
    <option value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="2">Saab</option>
    <option value="3">Fiat</option>
    <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
<select class="selectMe" name="options">
    <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
    <option value="4">Opt 4</option>
</select>
```

In wich part of the jquery plugin i must write the event and how?
How can i prevent double interations?

Comment: What do you want to click on to fire the event?  Are you trying to make it so some code runs when an option is selected?

Comment: @ScottKaye 
First: click on selOptions to show/hide his content (like when u click a select tag and toggle this option list).
Second: click an option of the list on selOptions to record in the hidden select with one was selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after you append the new list can use `find('li').click(fn)`

```
$("#"+selName+" .selOptions")
       .html("<ul>"+listOpt+"</ul>") /// your code ends here
       .find('li')
       .click(function(){
             var $li = $(this).addClass('selected');
             $li.siblings().removeClass('selected');
             sel.val( $li.data('value') ); // set value of select
        });
```

I would suggest you use some sort of prefix for your ID to avoid collisions with other items in the page.

Also, you shouldn't need `filter(".selectMe")` as you would likely call the plugin using:

```
$(".selectMe").selectMe()
```